# In Google Sheets in List View, can you add rows to the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using Google Sheets in List View (View->List View on the menu bar) as I have a fixed number of columns in my spreadsheet.

I'd like to add new rows to the end of the List instead of at the top of the list, but when I click the +Add button, it puts the new row at the top of the list instead of the bottom.

Is there anything I can do to change this functionality, so that new rows appear on the bottom of the list? (other than use Spreadsheet View of course).

Comment: "View->List View" doesn't seem to be a valid option...

Comment: I asked this question in 2010, I'm sure Google has changed it by now.

Comment: perhaps you should edit or delete the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested this myself, the fields to enter new data showed above the list, but when I clicked **Submit**, the row was sent to the bottom of the list and I got the message, "New row added. Jump to last page to view it." Are you seeing something different?

It makes sense for the new data fields to appear near the **+ Add** button, because that is where your focus is.