# Formatting a cell with word wrap without switching modes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

How can one format a cell to have word wrap in Google Sheets?

I've tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to work.

One thing I know works is to place [the spreadsheet into List Mode](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9868) and then if you edit your cell you can have word wrap in it.

But is there a way to do this without switching modes?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Google Spreadsheets should automatically wrap text when the content exceeds the width of the cell.

If not, you should be able to see a button on the toolbar to Wrap Text. Hit that when the focus is on the cell you want to wrap text for.

[image: wrap text on toolbar]

Alternatively you can force a linebreak in the cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: "should automatically wrap text" is kind of subjective ;) I for one am trying to figure out how to prevent that.

Comment: This seems to have moved to `Format > Text Wrapping > Wrap`

Comment: Upvoted for the wrapping art! Btw. it's still there, the icon just changed (it looks like an 'H').

Comment: Even selecting wrap, the content clips in my sheet. In other words, the cells do not become taller to accommodate the additional space needed. Perhaps another setting is preventing that to happen?

Answer (score 29):

[image: Text Wrap Option]

The button to change the text wrap option is slightly hidden. Hence, adding a screenshot from the new Google Sheets UI.

Answer (score 2):

```
First Select the Cell you want to Wrap
From The toolbar, select "Format" -> "Text Wrapping" -> "Wrap"
```

[image: How to Wrap Cell in Google Sheets]

Comment: Even selecting wrap, the content clips in my sheet. In other words, the cells do not become taller to accommodate the additional space needed. Perhaps another setting is preventing that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a new line when typing in a cell, instead of using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If the text wrapping is on overflow and you type like two sentences it will get cut off. But if you press the down arrow on the wrap button it will be the middle option. (If this helps any. the button is on the top right side of the command bar).

Answer (score -3):

An alternative to pasting just the long URL is to make a hyperlink - text that has a specific web address attached to it. By writing a short text word and turning this word into a hyperlink to your preferred URL works well.

Instruction are at [this hyperlink](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=spreadsheet%20drive%20hyperlink&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44660&ei=GCdmUeLoNLGQiQeVxIC4Aw&usg=AFQjCNGwvaQgYLbAsv2w2JF4ThniEfrRWg&sig2=k1HzPylWVZPaZJALfdAvGQ&bvm=bv.45107431,d.aGc)